# Pandas replace Values in a Column with values from another column but keep some values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I'm replacing some Values in a Dataframe column with values from an other Column like this:

```
df['A'] = df.ffill(1)['B']
```

But there are some values in Column A that I do not want to be replaced and keep them as they are.

The value I want to keep occurs many times and is a String so maybe there is a way to replace everything in column A with Column B but keep the values with a specific String?

Example:
So let's say my dataframe looks like this and I want to keep the value dog from Column A then I replace the rest of the values (except for the NaN values) with the values from Column B how would I do that.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'spider', 'fish', 'dog'],
                   'B': ['New York', 'London', np.nan, 'Berlin', np.nan, 
                         'Paris']})
```

The reslut should look like this:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['dog', 'London', 'mouse', 'Berlin', 'fish', 
                                'Paris']})
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: What is expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'spider', 'fish', 'dog'],
                   'B': ['New York', 'London', np.nan, 'Berlin', np.nan,
                         'Paris']})

df.loc[(~df["A"].str.contains("dog"))&(df["B"].notnull()),"A"] = df["B"]

print (df)
#
        A         B
0     dog  New York
1  London    London
2   mouse       NaN
3  Berlin    Berlin
4    fish       NaN
5     dog     Paris
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to check for `not NaN` in column `B` and use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to only replace values in column `A` where the value is not equal ([`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)) to `dog`:

```
m1 = df['A'].ne('dog')
m2 = df['B'].notna()

df.loc[m1&m2, 'A'] = df['B']

        A         B
0     dog  New York
1  London    London
2   mouse       NaN
3  Berlin    Berlin
4    fish       NaN
5     dog     Paris
```

Comment: Almost where ever there is a nan value should not change the value in Column a means mouse and fish should remain in column a.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over the elements in 'A' and ensure that for the same row the value in 'B' is not `NaN`.

(There might be a much cleaner way of doing this using inbuilt `df` functions)

```
for x in range(len(df['A'])):
    if(df['A'][x] != "dog" and df['B'][x] != np.nan):
        df['A'][x] = df['B'][x]
```

Edit:

Cleaner way using loc

```
df.loc[(df['A'].ne('dog')) &(df['B'].notnull()) , 'A'] = df['B']
```